# Каково правило написания инициалов иностранных имён?

Tags: ономастика, сокращения, оформление-книги

Пожалуйста, проконсультируйте, каково правило написания инициалов иностранных имен? Например, почему на всех книгах серии "Гарри Поттер" от известного издательства автор написан как Дж. К. Роулинг, а не Д. К. Роулинг? Что за особое положение у этого "дж", даже если это транслитерация буквы J?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Вопрос № 269816](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0)
Скажите, пожалуйста, иностранные имена типа Джек, Джон, Джойс (жен. имя) следует в русском варианте сокращать "Д." или "Дж."? Встречались в исследованиях оба варианта, какой все же верный?
**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
**1.** Транслитерируется инициал имени: **J.** — **Дж.** (как Джоуль).

В справочнике "Иностранные имена и названия в русском тексте" ([стр. 81](https://www.phantastike.com/linguistics/foreign_names_titles/djvu/view/)):
**J j —> Дж.**

Транслитерация — передача текста, написанного с помощью одного алфавита, средствами другого алфавита (а фонема ***D d***, близкая русскому ***д***, уже занята; стр. 68).

Answer (score 2):

В оригинальном языке (в нашем случае - английском) полное имя выглядит как "Joanne". Соответственно, инициал будет "J".
В русском языке действует прицип фонетической транслитерации, согласно которому иноязычные слова записываются так, как они звучат, а не так, как пишутся (и из-за этого, кстати, английский "Charles" пишется "Чарльз", а французский "Charles" пишется "Шарль", хотя это одно и то же имя). При этом
Буква "J" в английском звучит как "Дж" (на наш слух, конечно, потому что на самом деле там не два звука "д" и "ж", а одна аффриката, да еще и мягкая - это отсутствующая в русском практическом произношении звонкая пара звука "ч" (по тому же принципу, что звонкой парой звука "ш" является звук "ж").
Другими словами, произносить "дж" надо слитно, не разделяя на составляющие. Мы же умеем слитно произнести звук "ц", не разделяя его на "т" и "с". Так и здесь.
Указание инициала "Дж" является вполне разумным, потому что указывает нам на максимально приближенное к истине звучание первой буквы иностранного имени.
P.S. Кстати, звук "джь" не такой уж и чуждый для нас. Он прекрасно сохранился и употребляется в некоторых южнославянских языках, а в сербской кириллице для него даже есть отдельная буква.